# Convert int back to datetime?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The database table with a datetime column is read and returned by a restful api.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DATETIME
class Table(base)
    datetime = Column(DATETIME)
```

However, the API return integers for the column `datetime`.

```
1622332800000
1622937600000
1623542400000
1624147200000
```

How to convert these values back to datetime?

Comment: what will be your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1002332800)
timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The output should be:

```
>>>> 2001-10-06 04:46:40
```

Comment: The values I have is larger. Maybe my number should be divided by 1000?

Comment: Hi @ca9163d9 not sure if the dividing by 1000 will not change the actual date. But you may give it a try and let us know if it works for you.